# How to return unmatched string in expect

Tags: bash, return, tcl, expect

In my script I want to return the string that does not match .
I tried `puts $expect_out(buffer)` but it did not work and gave me below error

```
can't read "expect_out(buffer)": no such variable
    while executing
"puts "out is $expect_out(buffer)" "
```

## code

```
expect {
     -nocase -re "$arg3" { exit 0 } 
    timeout  { puts "Does not matched, output is $expect_out(buffer)" ; exit 2 }"
}
```

Comment: Your code and your error message don't quite match; it's as well to copy things across _exactly_ so that subtleties don't cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

The `expect_out` array doesn't exist until a match occurs, so if you haven't matched an expect call in your code previously and you actually reach your timeout clause, you receive the `no such variable` error.

> **Expect manpage**
>
> "Upon matching a pattern (or eof or full_buffer), any matching and previously unmatched output is saved in the variable expect_out(buffer). Up to 9 regexp substring matches are saved in the variables expect_out(1,string) through expect_out(9,string). If the -indices flag is used before a pattern, the starting and ending indices (in a form suitable for lrange) of the 10 strings are stored in the variables expect_out(X,start) and expect_out(X,end) where X is a digit, corresponds to the substring position in the buffer. 0 refers to strings which matched the entire pattern and is generated for glob patterns as well as regexp patterns."

You can test this via `info exists expect_out` and printing out the array keys/values (if it exists) using `array names expect_out`.

You can set the values explicity yourself via `set expect_out(key) value`, but there's no way (that I know of) to retrieve the non-matching string initially, bar using `log_file expectoutput.txt` and reading it back in if you timeout.